# Array doesn't populate at 0

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

So I store 10 strings to an array. Then I loop through a worksheet and add more elements to the array starting at position 10 (11th element). Works fine.

```
arr = Array("Summary", "Account Summary", "Calendarization", "Vehicles", "Buildings", "Personal Comp", "Comp Equip", _
                "Software", "Furn & Fixtures", "Alloc Deprec")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PrintTabCheck")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 6 To lastRow
        If .Cells(i, 4) <> 9999999 Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
            arr(UBound(arr)) = .Cells(i, 2).Value
            Debug.Print arr(UBound(arr))
        End If
    Next
End With
```

But sometimes I don't store anything to the array first before I loop so I figured I can start populating array at `i-6` (position 0) but I get a `run time error 13 type mismatch error` on line `arr(i-6) = .Cells(i, 2).Value` ;_;

This happens because the first cell to trigger `true` is on row 9 not 6. I tried doing `arr(i - 6 - b) = .Cells(i, 2).Value` where `b=3` but still no ;_;

As a work around, I am adding a "dummy" string to the array first then replicating as above.

```
arr = Array("dummy")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PrintTabCheck")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 6 To lastRow
        If .Cells(i, 4) <> 9999999 Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
            arr(UBound(arr)) = .Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
    Next
End With
```

But this is stupid XD Why can't I populate the array at position 0 without having to resort to adding a dummy element???

I declared it as `Dim arr As Variant`

Comment: Because it is NOT an array until you make it one. It is a simple variant.

Comment: So I declare it as `dim arr() as variant`? Edit: nope. Got `subscript out of range error` XD

Comment: You could, but if you only wish to store strings you could declare it like so: `Dim arr() As String`

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to use `Redim arr(0)` - `Ubound(arr)` will fail.

Comment: Right but I think the issue is because it wants to start at 3 not 0 XD

Comment: Regardless of the type of the array, you will need to ReDim it before you start assigning element values.

Comment: No. It does not want to start at 3.

Comment: You can `Redim` with whatever size you want. Note you can't declare it as `String` if you want to use the `Array` operator to assign an array to it.

Comment: `Redim arr(0)` and `Redim arr(99)` failed :/

Comment: Dim arr() As Variant

Comment: Then Redim arr(n) will work.

Comment: Subscript out of range XD Edit: the issue is `arr(i - 6)=` edit2: i =9 for first element.

Comment: There must be more to your code that is somehow interfering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91869/discussion-between-excel-hero-and-findwindow).

Comment: chat blocked :/ See edit. The issue is that it wants to start at 3 Edit: yep, changing to `i-9` worked.

Comment: Please send it to me. daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: Data is confidential :/

Comment: So, it is working now?

Comment: no. going to try to add b and increment that.

Comment: OK. If you can't work it out, send me a sanitized small sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sigh. The problem is that it wants to start at 3. You said it yourself above that it doesn't want to start at 3 XD I just need a separate increment to subtract. Edit: actually I need two?

Comment: It is interesting that `redim arr(0)` did not work, I added it right above the for statement in you second example and it worked for me.

Comment: @ScottCraner sigh. It's not the redim. It's that it starts at 3 XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
Sub arrtest()
Dim arr() As String
Dim t&, i&, lastrow&, firstrow&

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For t = 6 To lastRow
            If .Cells(t, 4) <> 9999999 Then
                firstrow = t - 6
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
          ReDim arr(firstrow To firstrow)
        For i = 6 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, 4) <> 9999999 Then

                    ReDim Preserve arr(firstrow To UBound(arr) + 1)
                    arr(UBound(arr)) = .Cells(i, 2).value

            End If
        Next
        For t = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

        Debug.Print arr(t)
        Next
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: It works but I don't get it. First element stored to array starts at position 4? (if firstrow =3)

Comment: @findwindow it is because the if statement adds 1 to the array then loads to the upper bound.  Switch the two statements it should work.

Comment: I thought array has to fill starting at 0?

Comment: @findwindow sorry I thought your question was rhetorical.  The lower bound can be anything you want.  It defaults to 0 if not specified.  But by stating arr(lowerbound to upperbound) you can make it anything; 100 to 110 or even 100000001 to 100000008.  This way you can use a variable and not need to do any math later.  Math is hard work, and best avoided at any cost.

Comment: lol I just got it ^_^; Wait, but then 3 is empty here? You add 1 to ubound first before storing? Edit: oh redim doesn't change ubound until it's filled?

Comment: Nope. Guess you don't have to fill first position. Thanks.

Comment: Ha. This fails when I try to loop through array later. `lbound` is empty XD

Comment: @findwindow before you loop check if empty and start loop at lbound(arr) +1

Comment: Yea.... on error resume next works too. Just kinda dumb that it's impossible to fill array from 0 XD